# Cannot find audio file type

Tags: file-format, audio

I'm trying to find the audio file type of [this file (extension wtj) around 8 minutes)](https://we.tl/t-jwAMjq5A5g). I extracted it from a music box.

I've tried many things:

- Open in Winamp and VLC => no luck
- Open with Audacity (no luck). I tried to import as a raw audio (every format) => no luck
- I tried the command line `file` on my mac (by the way is there any difference with the linux one?) => no luck
- I tried [TrId](https://superuser.com/questions/274734/how-can-i-determine-file-type-without-an-extension-on-windows) => no luck
- I tried Spek and GSpot => They cannot open the file
- I opened it in a hex editor, this is what I have

  09 0D 42 F2 F6 F9 06 F6 F6 9F F6 F6 F6 FE F6 F6 FB D6 F6 F6 F7 F6 F6 F7 52 F6 F6 F6 D6 F6 F6 C2 76 F6 F6 F2 BA B7 BB B3 C5 D8 CF CF D8 C3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 BA B7 BB B3 C5 D8 CF CF D8 C3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3

  09 0D 42 F2 F6 F9 06 F6 F6 9F F6 F6 F6 FE F6 F6 (//the sequence starts again 41 times and then we have)

  09 0D 42 F2 F6 F9 06 F6 F6 9F F6 F6 F6 FE F6 F6 FB D6 F6 F6 F7 F6 F6 F7 52 F6 F6 F6 D6 F6 F6 C2 76 F6 F6 F2 BA B7 BB B3 C5 D8 CF CF D8 C3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 E6 75 C2 56 0D F1 6C 84 D4 78 6C 95 40 84 2A EA 94 9B EC 15 B5 F4 3E E1 E7 82 B0 E9 34 E0 93 30 D3 F7 8E FC B6 66 D3 F3 8A F7 B6 D1 E2 D4 28 D0 9E 05 06 1E AB 77 66 AE E1 D5 20 AA 21 B4 2E D8 F8 D1 D4 74 A0 CE 06 E3 7A 64 6A 70 74 74 DF 89 E4 86 23 78 C3 26 6D 71 CD C7 9A D8 FD FC 83 ED A7 CD B1 5F FB F2 D7 5A AD 31 EC 96 D5 15 0B D6 CB F2 47 62 41 61 C1 D4 28 AA 2F 01 BC A4 67 E9 49 48 07 B9 1F E8 B0 F0 BE D1 CF CD EA 9A B5

The files size are between 11MB to 46 MB for something like 16 minutes and between 5MB to 18MB for the short version (8 minutes). So I guess that it is compressed. I don't think it is encrypted because in the hex version, the starting sequence is repeated 41 times (unless the encryption key length is a multiple of the starting sequence).

Now I am stuck. Do you have any idea where I can dig?

Comment: If you have the audio data of the music box most likely you have the music box software, too. I would check it for used libraries. Also info on the used hardware (used [audio] chips could be helpful. May be the format is used by an decoder chip.

Comment: The data are on a SD card. The usb plug is used only to charge the box. I cannot access the software unless if I break the box.

Comment: And still no name of the box...